# how can i get rupee symbol in app through keyboard

Tags: android

can anybody help me in getting the Rupee currency symbol font in textview through keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>` it may be what you are looking for or

As alternative try adding this

`<string name="rs">\u20A8</string>`

in strings.xml and then use onKeyListener or whatever suits you to use rs string.
This will produce a symbol like  [image: Rs]

This is not characters written like Rs it is equivalent of \u20A8.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The first one \u20B9 probably for Rupee symbol as given at
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm.
As a alternative I gave Rs.